# doctrine:generate:entities and vendor bundles

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, composer-php

I'm trying to organize my project with a base code and external bundles as a plugins for the base project.

I've already registered the bundles in packagist and the "composer.phar install" command works as expected. The autoloader also works as expected, so everything is OK but the "php console doctrine:generate:entities ACSACSPanelDynHostBundle" command don't work at all. It returns the next message:

```
[RuntimeException]                                                                                                                                                   
Can't find base path for "ACSACSPanelDynHostBundle" (path: "/var/www/acspanel/vendor/acs/paneldynhost", destination: "/var/www/acspanel/vendor/acs/paneldynhost").
```

I tryied to use psr-4 in composer.json to define the namespace but it don't works either.
I would like to know what is the proper way to use the console commands with my vendor bundles.

The code of my bundle composer.json is:

```
{
        "name": "acs/paneldynhost",
        "description": "Dynhost service creation for ACSPanel",
        "keywords": ["dynamic domain","acspanel"],
        "type": "
        "autoload": {
            "psr-4": { "ACS\\ACSPanelDynHostBundle\\": "" }
        },
        "require": {
            "php": ">=5.3.3"
        },
        "require-dev": {
            "phpunit/phpunit": "3.7.*"
        }
    }
```

Comment: shouldn't the name of the bundle be "ACSPanelDynHostBundle" and not "ACSACSPanelDynHostBundle"?

Comment: The name of the bundle is ACSPanelDynHostBundle and the ACS is the vendor name

Comment: Anyway, the console doctrine:generate:entities is finding the bundle by this name, if not the error message would be other